# Unable to run ffmpeg with qProcess to extract a single frame from Vide

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to extract a single frame from a video using the QProcess in qt framework and ffmpeg and store it in a tmp folder. When I run the program in terminal command line it is able to extract it but not when QProcess runs it. I'm developing on a mac. What am I doing wrong.

```
QString extractSingleFrame(QString videoPath, QDir tmpDir)
{
    QString program = ffmpegPath();
    QProcess *ffmpegProcess = new QProcess();
    QString arguments;
    QFileInfo videoInfo(videoPath);
    QString videoName = videoInfo.fileName();

    QString firstFrameName(tmpDir.absolutePath() + "/" + videoName + ".jpg");
    arguments = " -y -i " + QDir::toNativeSeparators(videoPath)
                + " -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 -f image2 " + QDir::toNativeSeparators(firstFrameName);

    QFile::remove(firstFrameName);
    qDebug() << "Starting program" << program + arguments;
    ffmpegProcess->start(program + arguments);
    // ffmpegProcess->start(program , QStringList() <<  arguments); this also doesnt work
    if (ffmpegProcess->state() == QProcess::Starting){
       qDebug() << "program is starting" + ffmpegProcess->state();
    }
    ffmpegProcess->waitForFinished(-1);

    qDebug() << "done";

    delete ffmpegProcess;

    return firstFrameName;
}
```

This is the printed command
to start the program "ffmpeg -y -i "/Users/userX/test.mov" -vframes 1 -q:v 1 -f image2 "/var/folders/s1/vtv2cx36p3h0000gn/T/test-ywDBgj/test.mov.jpg""

Comment: The state is starting after running the ffmpeg->start

Comment: What do you actually see?  Does the `QProcess` ever finish?  Try connecting to the various [QProcess signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#signals) and monitor state changes, errors etc.  You might also want to use the [`QProcess::start(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) overload to avoid passing everything (possibly) through a shell.

Comment: ffmpegProcess->state() == QProcess::NotRunning  comes as true, not sure the best way to debug this.

Comment: As I said, you need to perform more thorough error checking.  Also, does the process have permission to write to `/var/folders/s1/vtv2cx36p3h0000gn/T/` -- does the directory exist?